# How do you solve $y^2+2xyy' = e^x$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would one solve this ODE?

$$y^{2}+2xyy'=e^{x}$$

I tried dividing everything by $x$:

$$\frac{y^{2}}{x} + 2yy' = \frac{e^{x}}{x}$$

and then I did a substitution $v=y^2 1/2ydv=dy$

and then i end up with

$$\frac{v}{x} + v' = \frac{e^{x}}{x}$$

and then I'm not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Variation of Parameters? Integrating Factor?

Comment: The transformed equation is linear, so all you need to is multiply it by $e^{\int 1/x\text{ }dx}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: the left hand side is $\frac{d(xy^2)}{dx}$.

Added: your last equation is essentially $\frac{d(xv)}{dx} = e^x$ (with $v = y^2$), hence $xy^2(x) = e^x + C$.

Comment: Do you think you could write it out? Still stuck.